# sklearn SVR poly won't fit data properly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to use sklearn to fit a polynomial curve to my data, and predict future data with that curve. However, all I end up with is a horizontal line obviously doesn't fit at all. I have tried scipy optimize and obtained a beautifully fitting curve, but I wish for a prediction from sklearn as well.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.svm import SVR


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):#function to convert bytes to string for the dates.
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

dataCSV = open('combined_data_sr2.csv')

comb_data = []

for line in dataCSV:
    if 'Date' not in line:
        comb_data.append(line)

date, data1, data2 = np.loadtxt(comb_data, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%d/%m/%Y')})

pred_x = list(zip(data1))



Xpre = np.reshape(pred_x, (len(pred_x), 1))#to ensure that the data has the correct dimensionality.
x = preprocessing.scale(Xpre)#scaling the data
y = data2

b = 3
x_train = x[b:]
x_test = x[:b]

y_train = y[b:]
y_test = y[:b]

regr = SVR(kernel='poly', degree=3)
g = regr.fit(x, y).predict(x)#just for fitting the data and seeing if the estimator is right


print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((regr.predict(x_test) - y_test) ** 2))

print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(x_test, y_test))


print ('Prediction input:',(x_test))
print ('Prediction:',(regr.predict(x_test)))
print ('Actual:',(y_test))


plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.hold('on')
plt.plot(x, g, color='green', label='LR')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output of that code:

```
Residual sum of squares: 98171635548288.23
Variance score: -900.75
Prediction input: [[ 1.85313098]
 [ 1.98736261]
 [ 2.11307418]]
Prediction: [ 15188181.21713208  15188243.6121402   15188310.2184889 ]
Actual: [ 25417186.  25216661.  24638877.]
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu3117h1dvxell6/figure_1.png?dl=0) is the fitted plot that comes out.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjhledqm0ax1cst/using%20scipy%20optimize.png?dl=0) is the fit I want to see, using scipy's optimize curve fit.

How do I get sklearn to fit my data the same way that scipy.optimize's curve_fit does? I want to be able to predict non-linear data.

Comment: Did you try different kernels and does the `degree` match that which you used with `scipy`? Those are the first things I would change. Also consider another `sklearn` algorithm - a lot of options under `sklearn.linear_models` will be a good start.

Comment: Yes, the scipy version is also degree 3. I've tried other models, such as the linear ones, but at best I get a line that follows the general direction of the data. However, those other regressors are still linear and seem like a poor fit given the curve of the data.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. One value prediction comes up regardless of supplied arguments.

Comment: I know it has been 2 years since the question, but the issue seems to be the pre processing of the data that you use to fit. If you don't pre process then you should get something closer to what you expect